# Why is Node js only handling X requests per second but neither memory, CPU nor network usage is saturated?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does Node js only handle like 6 outgoing https requests per second but neither memory, CPU nor network usage is saturated?

can anybody advise how companies building web crawlers upon node js can crawl like 2500 pages per second then ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: in general for example if you use the request package only 6 or 10 requests per second are handled ..I have tried to solve this for one year now ...I guess it is a node js limitation somehow ...running my setup on an ubuntu server with 4 cores and bandwith is 500M per second download

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the server is slow. We probably can't help you if you don't provide some code for us to test. You don't need to post the code that initially caused this. Just make a quick example.